# Comparing 2 text files (only compare specific things)

Tags: powershell, compare, text-files

I'm working on a script that is collecting Data.

I have file A.txt that looks like this:

```
PRS3152_1        00e0f4106f39 
EAQ3152_1        00E0F40E0A28 
POR3152_1        00E0F45E0AAB 
KLQ3152_1        00e0f4406e10
SWG3152_1        00e0f57Ae125
```

And file B.txt that looks like this:

```
00E0F40E0A28 
00E0F45E0AAB
00e0f4406e10 
00e0f4106f39
```

How can I check if the MAC addresses from B.txt exist in A.txt?
After that the script should delete the rows in A.txt where the MAC-addresses dont exist.

Comment: Have you figured out any part yet? How to read the files? How to search the data? How to delete something? Show some effort and the community is happy to help you further.

Comment: I found out how to compare the files but not how to compare specific things like in this case. Like I said "I'm not familiar with powershell". I'm for real a noob in powershell. Sorry if I seem lazy but I really got no clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$content1 = Get-Content "D:\B.txt"
$content2 = Get-Content "D:\A.txt"
$useFile = "D:\%%%%%useFile%%%%%.txt"
$doesntexist = $true
foreach($line in $content2)
{
    $doesntexist = $true
    $lineCut = $line.Remove(0,17)
    foreach($line2 in $content1)
    {
        if($lineCut -like $line2)
        {
            $doesntexist = $false
        }
    }

    if($doesntexist -eq $false)
    {
        Add-Content $useFile $line
    }


}
Remove-Item "D:\A.txt"
Rename-Item "D:\%%%%%useFile%%%%%.txt" "A.txt"
```

With a little help I managed to solve it. But thank you anyway <3

Answer (score 0):

Note that we usually don't answer questions that don't show any code/effort on your part to solve the problem. I'm making an exception this time, because the question is simple enough, but don't expect this to happen often.

Read B.txt into an array, then check the MAC address from each line of A.txt against that array, and write only those lines back to the file where you have a match:

```
# ForEach-Object and Where-Object are to remove whitespace and empty lines
$list = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\B.txt' |
        ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() } |
        Where-Object { $_ }

(Get-Content 'C:\path\to\A.txt') | Where-Object {
    $list -contains ($_ -split '\s+')[1]
} | Set-Content 'C:\path\to\A.txt'
```

The parentheses around the `Get-Content` are required, otherwise you wouldn't be able to write back to the same file (because it's still being read from).